# Is it possible to mute notification sound on ALL apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

I want to enable the sound button (left side of the iPhone X), but then I got the notification sound whenever I got a message on WeChat. I'm fine with disabling the notification sound on WeChat.

But then, there are other, numerious apps that send out the notification and whenever I get it, the notification sound is alerted.

So far I only found it is possible to disable the sound one by one on each app, but is there any global setting that disables it? I use iOS 11.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

Unfortunately, there is no way to do them all at once. You’ll have to do them individually.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way around to silence all notifications.
Goto settings >>Do Not Disturb >> Turn on
Also, choose the option 'Silence Always' instead of 'While iPhone is Locked'